In Amazon Connect and LexV2 integration, how to set 'SpellByLetter' for a slot
I am trying to get First name in AWS Connect using Lex V2. I like caller to spell their name. Where and how to specify the SpellByLetter for the slot.
I tried doing through Lambda, but it only takes effect on second attempt.
Lambda response:
{
  "sessionState": {
    "sessionAttributes": {},
    "dialogAction": {
      "slotToElicit": "FirstName",
      "slotElicitationStyle": "SpellByLetter",
      "type": "ElicitSlot",
      "message": {
        "contentType": "PlainText",
        "content": ","
      }
    },
    "intent": {
      "name": "callerName"
    },
    "messages": [
      {
        "contentType": "PlainText",
        "content": ","
      }
    ]
  }
 }

